# Glob Function in Google Colab not giving any output

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory, glob

I have used the following code in google colab it returned an empty list:

```
import glob,cv2

cv_img = []
for img in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\dataset_new\test\yawn\*.jpg'):
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    cv_img.append(n)
print(cv_img)
```

It always returns -->[]

But the same code in Jupyter returns an array of integers
[Jupyter Output for glob Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhPbq.png)

I need to use Google Colab for other modules so is there a way i can get this through Google Colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave a Windows-style path.

That path will not work on Google Colab because

1. it's a Windows path and Google Colab isn't Windows
2. the path refers to directories that may exist on your own computer, but they don't on Google Colab

Use a linux/unix-style path. Use a relative path to make the code more portable.

Comment: Can you mention what linux path/relative path might i use to avoid transferring heavy data files to drive?

Comment: no. colab is a web service. it *can't* access files that are only on your computer. it can access files that are on google drive. if you need to access arbitrary local files, run your code locally, not on colab.